# Ubuntu Drivers on Chromium OS?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, chromium-os

I recently managed to install Chromium OS to a flash drive. However, when I booted into Chromium OS, I found that neither wifi or ethernet worked, yet both wifi and ethernet work on my Ubuntu partition.

I was wondering if it was possible to copy the wifi and ethernet drivers from Ubuntu to Chromium OS. Have any of you tried this?

I'm running Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Althought Chrome OS and Ubuntu are both based on Linux kernels, you're unlikely to be able to copy kernel modules from one to the other. Compiled modules are very sensitive to the kernel version unless you take precautions when writing and compiling them. The people who prepare the drivers for Ubuntu have no reason to take such precautions, so the drivers will probably not load on Chrome OS.

If you get the source of the drivers and manage to compile them, there's a good chance they will work. But compiling a separate driver for a kernel is not a trivial task if the driver maker hasn't specifically made it easy.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try compiling from source
But after I get a 32 bit system up and running...

Answer (score 0):

I think Chromium OS, for now, is meant for a very limited selection of netbooks/laptops. You could try copying over kernel modules from another system and see what happens, it won't hurt, but I dubt if it will work. Is running Chromium OS in VirtualBox (or another VM) an alternative?

Comment: I'm running it off of a flash drive.

Comment: You can boot from a flash drive into an OS that does have ie. VirtualBox and then run Chromium OS.